# Debian bluetooth can't connect to anything

Tags: linux, bluetooth, debian

I'm trying to connect different devices with my devian-system (Headphones, Keyboards). The devices are shown in both tools I use so far `bluetoothctl` and the `blueman-applet`. But when I'm trying to pair the devices, errors popping up and the devices themselves won't work.

For example the output from *bluetoothctl*:

```
[bluetooth]# pair 28:00:E9:00:30:7C 
    Attempting to pair with 28:00:E9:00:30:7C
[CHG] Device 28:00:E9:00:30:7C Connected: yes
[Apple Wireless Keyboard]# paired-devices 
    Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationTimeout
[CHG] Device 28:00:E9:00:30:7C Connected: no
```

I'm wondering if this is a problem of the kernel or something (debian with **linux-image 4.6.0-1-amd64**). What can I do?